# How to get CPU usage in python 2.7 without using PSUtil

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, cpu, cpu-usage

Trying to get CPU usage in `Python` without using `PSUtil`.

I've tried the following but it always seems to report the same figure...

```
def getCPUuse():
    return(str(os.popen("top -n1 | awk '/Cpu\(s\):/ {print $2}'").readline().strip(\
)))

print(getCPUuse())
```

This always seems to report 3.7% even when I load up the CPU.

I have also tried the following...

```
str(round(float(os.popen('''grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage }' ''').readline()),2))
```

This always seems to return 5.12. Must admit I don't really know what the above does. If I enter `grep cpu /proc/stat` into the command line I get something like this...

```
cpu  74429 1 19596 1704779 5567 0 284 0 0 0
cpu0 19596 0 4965 422508 1640 0 279 0 0 0
cpu1 18564 1 4793 427115 1420 0 1 0 0 0
cpu2 19020 0 4861 426916 1206 0 2 0 0 0
cpu3 17249 0 4977 428240 1301 0 2 0 0 0
```

I'm guessing my command isn't properly extracting the values for all of my CPU cores from the above output?

My objective is to get total CPU % from my device (Raspberry PI) without using PSUtil. The figure should reflect what is displayed in the OS Task Manager.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What PSUtil, htop, mpstat and the like do, is reading the line starting with `"cpu"` (actually the first line) from `/proc/stat`, and then calculate a percentage from the values in that line.  You can find the meaning of the values on that line in `man 5 proc` (search for "proc/stat").

That's also what the `grep cpu /proc/stat | awk ....` command you mentioned does. But the values in `/proc/stat` represent the times spent since last boot! Maybe they wrap around after a while, I'm not sure, but the point is that these are numbers measured over a really long time.

So if you run that command, and run it again a few seconds (, minutes or even hours) later, they won't have changed much! That's why you saw it always return 5.12.

Programs like `top` remember the previous values and subtract them from the newly read values. From the result a 'live' percentage can be calculated that actually reflect recent CPU load.

To do something like that in python as simply as possible, but without running external commands to read `/proc/stat` and do the calculations for us, we can store the values we've read into a file. The next run we can read them back in, and subtract them from the new values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os.path

# Read first line from /proc/stat. It should start with "cpu"
# and contains times spent in various modes by all CPU's totalled.
#
with open("/proc/stat") as procfile:
    cpustats = procfile.readline().split()

# Sanity check
#
if cpustats[0] != 'cpu':
    raise ValueError("First line of /proc/stat not recognised")

#
# Refer to "man 5 proc" (search for /proc/stat) for information
# about which field means what.
#
# Here we do calculation as simple as possible:
# CPU% = 100 * time_doing_things / (time_doing_things + time_doing_nothing)
#

user_time = int(cpustats[1])    # time spent in user space
nice_time = int(cpustats[2])    # 'nice' time spent in user space
system_time = int(cpustats[3])  # time spent in kernel space

idle_time = int(cpustats[4])    # time spent idly
iowait_time = int(cpustats[5])    # time spent waiting is also doing nothing

time_doing_things = user_time + nice_time + system_time
time_doing_nothing = idle_time + iowait_time

# The times read from /proc/stat are total times, i.e. *all* times spent
# doing things and doing nothing since last boot.
#
# So to calculate  meaningful CPU % we need to know how much these values
# have *changed*.  So we store them in a file which we read next time the
# script is run.
# 
previous_values_file = "/tmp/prev.cpu"
prev_time_doing_things = 0
prev_time_doing_nothing = 0

try:
    with open(previous_values_file) as prev_file:
        prev1, prev2 = prev_file.readline().split()
    prev_time_doing_things = int(prev1)
    prev_time_doing_nothing = int(prev2)
except IOError:  # To prevent error/exception if file does not exist. We don't care.
    pass   

# Write the new values to the file to use next run
#
with open(previous_values_file, 'w') as prev_file:
    prev_file.write("{} {}\n".format(time_doing_things, time_doing_nothing))

# Calculate difference, i.e: how much the number have changed
#
diff_time_doing_things = time_doing_things - prev_time_doing_things
diff_time_doing_nothing = time_doing_nothing - prev_time_doing_nothing

# Calculate a percentage of change since last run:
#
cpu_percentage = 100.0 * diff_time_doing_things/ (diff_time_doing_things + diff_time_doing_nothing)

# Finally, output the result
#
print "CPU", cpu_percentage, "%"
```

Here's a version that, not unlike `top`, prints CPU usage every second, remembering CPU times from previous measurement in variables instead of a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os.path
import time

def get_cpu_times():
    # Read first line from /proc/stat. It should start with "cpu"
    # and contains times spend in various modes by all CPU's totalled.
    #
    with open("/proc/stat") as procfile:
        cpustats = procfile.readline().split()

    # Sanity check
    #
    if cpustats[0] != 'cpu':
        raise ValueError("First line of /proc/stat not recognised")

    # Refer to "man 5 proc" (search for /proc/stat) for information
    # about which field means what.
    #
    # Here we do calculation as simple as possible:
    #
    # CPU% = 100 * time-doing-things / (time_doing_things + time_doing_nothing)
    #

    user_time = int(cpustats[1])    # time spent in user space
    nice_time = int(cpustats[2])    # 'nice' time spent in user space
    system_time = int(cpustats[3])  # time spent in kernel space

    idle_time = int(cpustats[4])    # time spent idly
    iowait_time = int(cpustats[5])    # time spent waiting is also doing nothing

    time_doing_things = user_time + nice_time + system_time
    time_doing_nothing = idle_time + iowait_time

    return time_doing_things, time_doing_nothing


def cpu_percentage_loop():
    prev_time_doing_things = 0
    prev_time_doing_nothing = 0
    while True:  # loop forever printing CPU usage percentage
        time_doing_things, time_doing_nothing = get_cpu_times()
        diff_time_doing_things = time_doing_things - prev_time_doing_things
        diff_time_doing_nothing = time_doing_nothing - prev_time_doing_nothing
        cpu_percentage = 100.0 * diff_time_doing_things/ (diff_time_doing_things + diff_time_doing_nothing)

        # remember current values to subtract next iteration of the loop
        #
        prev_time_doing_things = time_doing_things
        prev_time_doing_nothing = time_doing_nothing

        # Output latest perccentage
        #
        print "CPU", cpu_percentage, "%"

        # Loop delay
        #
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cpu_percentage_loop()
```

Comment: Interesting solution. How much time do you think is needed in between each sample? I'm wondering if I can keep the current values in memory to avoid writing the file and just sleep for a specified amount of time before the comparison.

Comment: Sure, that is what top and htop do: they (by default) refresh every 1 second, and keep previous CPU times spent in memory for that 1 second.

Comment: "man 5 proc" states that the times are measured in "1/100ths  of  a  second on most architectures". So only when you start using times as short as, say, considerably shorter than 0.1 second, they start to become less meaningful.

Comment: Added a version of the python script that does not write a file, but remembers previous measurerment in variables.

Comment: Brilliant solution, +1 I don't know why this did not get enough upvotes !

Answer (score 1):

That's not really easy, since most of the process you describe provide the cumulative, or total average of the CPU usage.

Maybe you can try to use the `mpstat` command that comes with te `systat` package.

So, the steps I used for the following script are:

1. Ask `mpstat` to generate 2 reports, one right now and the other after 1 second (`mpstat 1 2`)
2. Then we get the `Average` line (the last line)
3. The last column is the `%idle` column, so we get that with the `$NF` variable from `awk`
4. We use `Popen` from subprocess but setting `shell=True` to accept our pipes (`|`) options.
5. We execute the command (`communicate()`)
6. Clean the output with a `strip`
7. And subtract that (the idle percentage) from 100, so we can get the used value.

Since it will sleep for `1 second`, don't be worry that it is not an *instant* command.

```
import subprocess                                      

cmd = "mpstat 1 2 | grep Average | awk '{print $NF}'"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)                                   
out, err = p.communicate()                   
idle = float(out.strip())                              
print(100-idle)
```